# Time Consuming WCF service call blocks the other WCF service calls.

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services, wcf-data-services

I am using a WCF service with my Silverlight 5 Application.

In one of my service calls I am doing a time consuming job. It takes 1 or 2 minutes to complete the event. I am not blocking the UI with busy indicators, so the user can still interact with the application.

The problem is when I do my first service call, it performs some time consuming operation. When the user loads some other, my second service call is not being processed until the first service is completed.

How can I perform the time consuming service call in separate thread to avoid other 
calls waiting for this service completion?

WebService Code

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TestService
{[OperationContract]
    public bool PerformFileScan(int fileID)
    {
    //Time Consuming Process
    }
}
```

cs

```
client.PerformFileScanAsnc(docId);
client.PerformFileScanCompleted += new EventHandler<.PerformFileScanCompletedEventArgs>(client_PerformFileScanCompleted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Make your call asynchronous on the server side. You can use the TPL and just write something like `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`
2. You can decorate your service implementation with the `ServiceBehavior` attribute and set the `ConcurrencyMode` to `Multiple`:

   ```
   [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]    
   public class YourService
   {

   }
   ```

Then wcf will schedule calls to your service in parallel. But then you have to ensure that your service code is threadsafe!